# How to redirect all page to 404 using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I want to redirect all pages on my site (including index) to 404 using htaccess.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this rule in root .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^ - [R=404,L]
```

Comment: How did you test? DO you have other rules also?

Comment: Yep, I forgot to mention I'm using wordpress, and it has BULLETPROOF.

Comment: In that case make this rule as very first rule in WP .htaccess file.

Answer (score 1):

The following works on newer apache:

```
Redirect 404
```

And you can add a message without creating a file like this:

```
ErrorDocument 404 "Hmm... There's nothing here..."
```